# Use htaccess to change file type, works on some servers, others it prompts download of file

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using htaccess to change a file extension from gif to php but it does not change on a particular test server, instead it prompts a download for the gif file which reveals the php.

The .htaccess file is in the same directory as the gif. The code looks like this, any ideas?

```
<Files trackme.gif>

ForceType application/x-httpd-php

</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SetHandler` instead of `ForceType`:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
# or
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
```

Comment: Thanks Floem, This did the trick, ForceType application/x-httpd-php5